# Why didn't the Ministry know what went on in the graveyard?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry and Cedric both had the trace. All three unforgivable curses were cast in their presence.

The trace tells you what spell is cast, where it's cast, and who is the presence of it.

We know this, because the Ministry knew that the Patronus charm was cast in the presence of Dudley.

How, exactly, did they not know Voldemort had returned, and killed Cedric?

Comment: They [presumably don't track Unforgivable Curses](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/50810/33591).

Comment: Cedric wasnt underage. .. good question, though, as Harry certainly was.